# Android - Can not create directory

Tags: android, android-studio, save, android-file, android-external-storage

I'm coding a app which connects over SFTP to a remote server and should download a .cvs file to the external storage of the mobile phone or the internal storage if theres no SD card.
SFTP connection does work fine but i got stuck with the file operations.

My problem currently is that if I want to create a directory on the mobile using mkdirs() it does not work. The app executes fine but nothing changes in the filesystem.

If I create the directory manually using a file manager my app crashes.

```
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


public void createdir() throws IOException{
    if (!isExternalStorageWritable()) {
        // No external storage available
        File directory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                + "/Remote/");

        if (directory.exists()) {                
            File[] dirFiles = directory.listFiles();
            if (dirFiles.length != 0) {
                for (int ii = 0; ii <= dirFiles.length; ii++) {
                    dirFiles[ii].delete();
                }
            }
        }

        if (!directory.exists()) { 
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
    } else {
        // External storage mounted
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "Remote");
        if (directory.exists()) {
            File[] dirFiles = directory.listFiles();
            if (dirFiles.length > 0) {
                for (int ii = 0; ii < dirFiles.length; ii++) {
                    dirFiles[ii].delete();
                }
                dirFiles = null;
            }
        }
        if (!directory.exists()) {                
            directory.mkdirs();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the device on which you are testing has an SD card? Also post your crash logs.

Comment: Could also be because you are trying to create a directory from a file. If "Remote" is Folder Name then instead try `new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/Remote");` If not then give the file an extension.

Comment: @Abbas I'm testing on a Nexus 7 and the device does not have a SD card. However, when exploring the filesystem, it somehow emulates a SD card. But the function isExternalStorageWriteable() always returns true so I assume that this "SD card emulating thing" is not the problem.

Your hint with "/Remote" did not change anything :(
I will post the crash logs in a minute